# Coffeescript SyntaxError: unexpected LOGIC

Tags: coffeescript

I just set up coffeelint on Atom. I was getting plenty of warnings like this one:

```
if HelpersValidators.isNotEmpty(email) and HelpersValidators.isNotEmpty(password) and HelpersValidators.isEmail(email) and HelpersValidators.areValidPasswords(password, passwordConfirm)
   ...

=> Line exceeds maximum allowed length
```

So what I did is:

```
if HelpersValidators.isNotEmpty(email)
  and HelpersValidators.isNotEmpty(password)
  and HelpersValidators.isEmail(email)
  and HelpersValidators.areValidPasswords(password, passwordConfirm)
```

But now, I'm getting the following error and I can't resolve it.

```
=> SyntaxError: unexpected LOGIC
```

So how can I structure this condition to make it appear on several lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't start new line with logic operator in CoffeeScript, so you should fold the line afret `and` operator, not before it:

```
if HelpersValidators.isNotEmpty(email) and
   HelpersValidators.isNotEmpty(password) and
   HelpersValidators.isEmail(email) and
   HelpersValidators.areValidPasswords(password, passwordConfirm)
  // do something
```

or

```
if HelpersValidators.isNotEmpty(email) and
  HelpersValidators.isNotEmpty(password) and
  HelpersValidators.isEmail(email) and
  HelpersValidators.areValidPasswords(password, passwordConfirm)
    // do something
```